# Django admin redirect issue (unintended redirect to '.../?e=1')

Tags: python, django, redirect, calendar, django-admin

I'm trying to write a simple calendar app called 'cal' in django and I modify the event (model) registration for visualize the calendar also in the changelist_view (`/admin/cal/event/`). I wrote two functions (prev_month and next_month) that return a url with two parameters with the month and the year (`'?month={month}&year={year}'`) to be displayed. When i go to this url, in server side, the page is rendered, but instead of sending the HTML it redirects to this URL `/admin/cal/event/?e=1` and the month doesn't change.

```
#admin.py
@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formatted_date(self, obj):
        return obj.event_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    formatted_date.short_description = 'Formatted Date'
    
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
        year = int(request.GET.get('year', datetime.today().year))
        month = int(request.GET.get('month', datetime.today().month))
        
        d = date(year, month, day=1)
        cal = CalendarAdmin(d.year, d.month)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
    
        extra_context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        extra_context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        extra_context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
    
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)


def prev_month(d):
    first = d.replace(day=1)
    prev_month = first - timedelta(days=1)
    month = str(prev_month.month)
    year = str(prev_month.year)
    return f'month={month}&year={year}'

def next_month(d):
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]
    last = d.replace(day=days_in_month)
    next_month = last + timedelta(days=1)
    month = str(next_month.month)
    year = str(next_month.year)
    return f'month={month}&year={year}'
```

CalendarAdmin is a simple class to generate a calendar.

I've tried everything, I modify the CalendarAdmin class, the EventAdmin class, the deafault django config file and in the end I've tried to put some `print()` and I understood that the problem is only that something redirect the request GET to a url without the parameters and so the function set the current month to default and the month doesn't change. Is there a way to fix it?
I hope somebody help me, thanks for reading.

*Django version = 4.2, python version= 3.12*